# Firebase - Check whether the data has a child or not

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table and a category page and these categories can hold documents. My category index page shows all my categories, with the option to delete the one I want. I just want it to be possible to exclude if the category does not have any documents.

My structure is:

[image]

The part of my code that deletes the category is this:

```
$('.exclude i').click(function(){
                        if(categoriasRef.child($(this).parent().attr('keyCategoria')).child('documentos')){
                            if(confirm("Você realmente deseja apagar esse registro?")){
                                categoriasRef.child($(this).parent().attr('keyCategoria')).remove();
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

I tried adding:

> if(categoriasRef.child($(this).parent().attr('keyCategoria')).child('documentos'))

, but this condition is always right even if the category does not have documents like your child, so the condition always goes through and you can delete the category.

I do not know how I can differentiate the categories with documents and without attached documents so that I can do the processing of which if they have documents can not be deleted.

whole code for better understanding:

```
function initFirebase(){

        function carregaCategorias(){
            categoriasRef.on('value', function(data){
                headertb = isAdmin ? "<th>Categoria</th><th>Editar</th><th>Excluir</th>" : "<th>Categoria</th>";
                $('#tableCustom thead tr').html(headertb);

                $("#tableCustom").dataTable().fnDestroy();
                $('#tableCustom tbody').html('');

                for(var key in data.val()){
                    categoria = data.val()[key]
                    if(isAdmin){
                        linha = "<tr>"+
                                    "<td>"+categoria.titulo+"</td>"+
                                    "<td><a href='/categorias/"+key+"/edit/'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a></td>"+
                                    "<td class='exclude' keyCategoria='"+key+"'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></td>"+
                                "</tr>";
                        $('#tableCustom').append(linha);
                    }else{
                        window.location = "/documentos?estado=not_admin";
                    }


                }

                closeLoader();

                //datatable        
                $('#tableCustom').dataTable({
                    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sUrl": "/datatable_pt.txt"
                    },
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
                        { "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
                        { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
                    ]
                });


                if(isAdmin){
                    $('.exclude i').click(function(){
                        if(categoriasRef.child($(this).parent().attr('keyCategoria')).child('documentos')){
                            if(confirm("Você realmente deseja apagar esse registro?")){
                                categoriasRef.child($(this).parent().attr('keyCategoria')).remove();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }); 
        }

        carregaCategorias();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use exists?

[Here the exists documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I've got this: data.child($(this).parent().attr('keyCategoria')).child('documentos').exists()

Comment: could you try something like this 

  if (categoriesRef.child($(this).parent().Attr('keyCategory')+"/"+'documents').exists()
 
inside the function child() you can send all your URL